# Help With Vector Images

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, inkscape, corel-draw, laser-cutting

I'm having some trouble with a vector image I downloaded from shutterstock. I'm trying to lasercut a Christmas present for my cousin. I need to be able to get an outline of the vector image (it's composed of many parts) so that I can cut the shape out of acrylic then engrave the details on that cutout. I can easily do this once I can get an outline. I have access to inkscape, corel draw and adobe illustrator, and have tried various combinations of combining parts, tracing images, taking unions of vector paths, but none of them work. Suggestions?

In the picture below, (a) is two different vector paths. I'm trying to get (b), which is one vector path.

[image: Diagram of what I'm trying to do]

Comment: In Illustrator that's done by selecting both and then using the Union command. I'm not sure why that didn't work but it should based on your sketch.

Comment: The same for Inkscape.

Comment: Are there any possible problems when using this for laser cutting? e.g. compound shapes being etched as individual outlines or whatever?

Comment: I've done a fair bit of lasercutting with raster/vector mixes and the laser cutter has handled it okay so far, although they were much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Adobe Illustrator, here is how to combine `Shapes` in the way you describe:

1. Select the two `Shapes` you want to "join".
2. Under the Pathfinder palette, select `Unite`.
3. Done.

[image]

[image]

There may be some other tweaking or options depending on whether you are actually using Paths, Strokes or Shapes, whether they're filled, outlined, etc. With lines/outlines, you may need to adjust whether the stroke is inside/outside the shape or the Corner/Cap. It is difficult to tell without seeing exactly how the shape is drawn.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I usually start editing vectors for the laser cutter by converting everything to paths, then changing the line width to hairline (~0.01").

Comment: Would it be helpful if I showed the vector I downloaded from shutterstock?

Comment: It couldn't hurt. The shapes I used in the demo above are still paths with a 1px stroke. This method should work in your case.

Comment: Got a 404 on that link.

Comment: My bad. Was trying not to give you a mobile link. Here it is. http://www.shutterstock.com/pic.mhtml?id=94802731

Comment: I've successfully isolated the shoes on their own but as soon as I try and get an outline I'm stuck.

Comment: I'm not following which outline you're stuck on. But if you have the lacing separate, the next step should be to unite the two paths. Are they not paths?

Comment: They are paths. I'm using the leftmost pair of shoes, which overlap. I do have them as paths, which is why I'm unsure why the union didn't behave how I expected. I guess I'll go back and make sure everything is a path then try again.

Comment: For some reason I had to do it twice, (and break apart the path in between) but it finally worked. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked.